# how to read text new line from a text file in raw and display it on different text views

Tags: android

I'm trying to creat text views through loop
and each new line in my text file should display on another text view.
BUt getting all the text on a single text view instaed of different lines on different textviews.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

            PlayWithRawFiles();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }// onCreate

    public void PlayWithRawFiles() throws IOException {

        int i;

        String str="";

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.status);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        if (is!=null) {

            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buf.append(str + "\n" );

                RelativeLayout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rlp.setMargins(0,5,0,5);

                for (i=0; i<100; i++)
                {
                    TextView tv = new Text View(this);
                    tv.setText(buf.toString());
                    tv.setTextSize(20);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(rlp);
                    rl.addView(b);
                }
            }

        }

        is.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take `LinearLayout` instead

Comment: Just looking at your logic here I assume the following:  
1.)You read one line in the file.  
2.)Then you create your RelativeLayout.  
3.) After that you create 100 TextViews with the line you read from step 1.  
4.) Then (assuming "b" is a typo) add each TextView to your layout.

This would add 100 TextViews all with the same string.  Is this what you are seeing?  Yes, a Linear layout would solve the single line issue, but I believe there is a much bigger issue in your logic.  Unless this is what you intend.

Comment: each different string in the text file should display on different text views each

Comment: tried with linear layout but only the first string displays in one text view and the other strings do not

Comment: `for (i=0; i<100; i++)`. Change to `//for (i=0; i<100; i++)`. And change `tv.setText(buf.toString());` to `tv.setText(str);`.

Comment: `RelativeLayout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rlp.setMargins(0,5,0,5);`. Do that before the while loop.
`